# Find a and b such that this limit is equal to an answer.

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a+\frac{n+1}{bn^2+n+2})^{n+2}=\frac1e$

So I tried to get to the common denominator and then add 1 and substract 1 inside the power to create the case $1^\infty$. But I get to something really absurd and wrong. What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: To make it $1^\infty$, you just need $a=1$ and $b\neq0$, so that's relatively easy. The real work is to choose $b$ so that the fraction goes to $0$ at the exact right pace to give your limit.

Comment: @Arthur: $b$ may be zero and $a=b=0$ is also a valid solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the limit for $e^x$ is as follows:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+{x \over n}\right)^{n}$$

So to achieve $\frac{1}{e}$, $x$ must be $-1$. You get this by using $a=1$ and $b=-1$ and factoring:

$$\require{cancel} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{n+1}{-n^2+n+2}\right)^{n+2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{\cancel{n+1}}{-1(n-2)(\cancel{n+1})}\right)^{n+2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n-2}\right)^{n+2}$$

And using some manipulation:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n-2}\right)^{n+2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n-2}\right)^{n-2}\right]^{n+2\over n-2}= \left({1 \over e}\right)^1$$

Comment: Nice derivation, to show the last, better than asymptotic, note that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n-2}\right)^{n+2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n-2}\right)^{n-2}\right]^\frac{n+2}{n-2}=\frac1e$$

Comment: @gimusi Yep, let me add that. Thanks!

Comment: The last step is not correct in this way, you can take the limit and obtain $$..=\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{1} = {1 \over e}$$

Comment: The fact is that it is not correct to take the two limits separetely if you have $f(x)\to a$ and $g(x)\to b$ then $(f(x))^{g(x)}\to a^b$ and not $(f(x))^{g(x)}\to (f(x))^b\to a^b$.

Comment: @gimusi Oh, I've got it. Let me edit.

Comment: Your solution misses the case $a=b=0$ which works fine.

Comment: You can not logically deduce $b=-1$ in the manner you have done.

Comment: In short you have just verified that $a=1,b=-1$ works and not that you have found the logical solution. You may want to fix this to reverse the downvote.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the comment—you're completely right. Since you've already posed a good explanation, I think it'd be better to get the asker to unaccept mine and accept yours instead of me getting the credit for an unhelpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The right approach is to take logs here. By the given conditions we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (n+2)\log\left (a+\frac{n+1}{bn^2+n+2}\right) =-1\tag{1}$$ and this implies that the log term in above equation tends to $0$. Therefore the argument of the log term tends to $1$ ie $$a+\frac{n+1}{bn^2+n+2}\to 1\tag{2}$$ If $b\neq 0$ then this means that $a=1$ and then from equation $(1)$ we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{bn^2+n+2}\cdot \frac{bn^2+n+2}{n+1}\log\left(1+\frac{n+1}{bn^2+n+2}\right)=-1$$ ie $1/b=-1$ so that $b=-1$.

All of the above is based on the assumption that $b\neq 0$. Let's see what happens when $b=0$. Clearly in that case argument of logarithm tends to $a+1$ so that $a=0$. It is easy to see that in this case also the equation $(1)$ holds so that we have two sets of values for $a, b$ which satisfy the given conditions: $a=1,b=-1$ and $a=b=0$.